# How can i get SESSION variables to work when the variable is set in a function? displaying index not set

Tags: php, session, session-variables, superglobals

The issue i have is that within my login system of a database, i create session variables within a function so that they can be used in another file however they do not seem to be accessible outside of that files function meaning when i try to call the session variable in the other file it gives me a index not set error.

so far ive tried globalising the variables although im not sure how else to go about this issue any help would be appreciated.

[session variables set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMZxz.png)

[session variables being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Sus.png)

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: yes i will edit